Integrate Vuforia Unity Application as aar file in Android Studio. Unable to load DLL 'VuforiaEngine'
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1
Vuforia 10.22.5
I'm attempting to integrate the generated aar file from the Android project that was generated from Unity with the Vuforia library, into my Android project.
The Android project with the unity library works and also when I'm using the project as a module in my Android project. but when I'm trying to generate the project to aar file it gives me an error, As I saw the aar file that was generated includes more than 2 aar files. [VuforiaEngine,unityandroidpermissions]. In the end, the project built as aar files are needed for the Maui project.
 ****DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'VuforiaEngine'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'VuforiaEngine' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) dlerror() = dlopen failed: library "VuforiaEngine" not found
 at **Vuforia.VuEngineConfigSet.vuEngineConfigSetCreate (System.IntPtr& configSetHandle) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
 at Vuforia.VuEngineConfigSet.Create () [0x00000] in 
 <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
 at Vuforia.Internal.NativeBridge.NativeEngineConfigSet..ctor
(Vuforia.VuforiaConfiguration vuforiaConfiguration) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Vuforia.Internal.NativeBridge.NativeEngineConfigSet..ctor (Vuforia.VuforiaConfiguration vuforiaConfiguration, System.String recordingPath) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at Vuforia.Internal.NativeBridge.NativeEngineFactory.CreateEngineConfig (Vuforia.VuforiaConfiguration vuforiaConfiguration, System.String recordi**



Tried to publish both AAR files to Maven and then use the whole project as AAR but still did not work.
